# Can someone make this text more "native"?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

I don't know Korean very well, but it's my korean friend's birthday and I want to make a surprise to her writing this in Korean. Can any korean make this little text sound more like a native? I appreciate it

언니! 생일 축하합니다 !! 언니처럼 특별한 사람에게 바라는 것은 생각하기 어렵다. 항상 좋은 일만 가득하길 바라며, 당신이 누구이고, 당신이 될 사람이 자랑스럽다.

Answer (score 1):

언니! 생일 축하해요!! 언니처럼 제게 특별한 사람에게는 저는 아무것도 바랄 것이 없어요. 항상 좋은 일만 가득하길 바랍니다. 언니의 현재와 미래의 모습을 생각하면 자랑스러워요!

Try this out please. But I think it would be better for you to include the original English sentences you are trying to say.